# Are failed Windows 7 backups logged anywhere?

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

In Windows XP, failed backups were logged in a way that I could view the event using the Event Viewer.

Is there a similar feature in Windows 7?

Comment: Windows Backup and Restore is troublesome. I suggest using instead a 3rd-party product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are, in the Event Viewer. Look under `Windows Logs` > `Application` in the Event Viewer for events from Windows Backup and Restore. A failed backup will generally appear as an "Error" entry from "Windows Backup" source, and an event ID of `4106`.